# Set Hyperlink to picture gives redundant filepath

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I want to add a webaddress to my picture as a hyperlink. My code is:

```
Public Sub insert_video_from_file(a As Worksheet)
...    
    hoehe = Application.CentimetersToPoints(4.96)
    breite = Application.CentimetersToPoints(2)

a.Activate
'Set objPicture = InsertPicture("C:\Users\VEKO\Desktop\GPTW_logo.jpg", Cells(1, 1), strReturnMsg, hoehe, breite)
Set objPicture = InsertPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\video.jpg", Cells(1, 1), strReturnMsg, hoehe, breite)

    objPicture.Name = "video" 'Name vergeben
    With a
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Shapes.Name(objPicture.Name), Address:= "www.google.de"
    End With
    Set objPicture = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get a hyperlink set to the picture but the hyperlink is "Path to the file" + www.google.de `(e.g. C://User/Desctop/www.google.de)`. I checked the internet and the examples give me the same .hyperlinks.add anchor code I used so I do not know why the path is set. Anyone who can help me here?

Comment: Dont you need to use `http://` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTTP://` is required and your anchor is also wrong:

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=objPicture, Address:= "http://www.google.de"
```